# Questions regarding congruent numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have two questions regarding congruent numbers :

1. According to the book Discrete mathematics and its applications by Rosen , we have the following  theorem :
   [image]

So this means that we can multiply a congruent relation by itself ?
I mean if we have a ≡ b (mod m)  , is it valid to say that a.a ≡ b.b (mod m) -> a^2 ≡ b^2 ( mod m) according to the above theorem ?

2. Can we substitute directly in congruent relations in any case ? I mean if we have  a ≡ b (mod m)  and d ≡ (z*a)^2 (mod m) , where a,b,d,z and m are all integers  , so can we substitute with a =b in the second relation to have d ≡ (z*b)^2 (mod m) ?

Comment: Yes, you can substitute the way you suggest. Note, however, that not all substitutions are allowed.  For example, $3\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.  But $2^3\not \equiv 2^0\pmod 3$.

Comment: Side note:  the term [Congruent Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number) has a very specific meaning, which is not the meaning you intend.  Specifically, a congruent number is a natural number that can be realized as the area of a right triangle with rational sides.

Comment: @lulu Thanks , but can we multiply a congruent relation by itself ?

Comment: That phrasing is unclear.  But if $a\equiv b \pmod n$ and $c\equiv d\pmod n$ then yes, $ac\equiv bd\pmod n$.

Answer (score 0):

if x ≡ y (mod m) and a ≡ b (mod m)
x = y + m*k
a = b + m*p
sum of them is:  m*(k+p) +y + b = y + b(mod m)

Note: no matter if y + b is over than m -->   14 == 9 (mod 5)
as for multipication thats a so common thing we use in modular arithmetic questions
For example,

in mod 5:

```
3^0 ≡ 1
3^1 ≡ 3 
3^2 ≡ 4 --> 3*3 = 9≡ 4 (mod 5) 
3^3 ≡ 2 --> 4*3 = 12 ≡ 2 (mod 5)
3^4 ≡ 1
...
```

thus

```
3^4k ≡ 1 (mod 5)
3^4k+1 ≡ 3 (mod 5)
3^4k+2 ≡ 4 (mod 5)
3^4k+3 ≡ 2 (mod 5)
```

there are many shortcuts you will be accustomed to as you learn

Good luck in your learning journey!